Can't see the content of the formData in the Node js backend
I want send the zod form using formData using a post method. When I console.log the formData in the front-end, it displays the result but in the back-end, the req.body is empty and the req.file is undefine
async function onSubmit (data: z.infer){
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append("fullname", data.fullname);

// Append the entire file object
if (data.contactFile) {
  formData.append("contactFile", data.contactFile); // This is the full File object
}

for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
  console.log(`${key}:`, value);
}

try {
  const response = await apiClient.create("/contact", formData);
  toast(`${response.message}`, {
    type: 'success',
  });
} catch (error: any) {
  toast(`Error: ${error.message}`, {
    type: "err`enter code here`or",
  });
}

this is the result in the backend
"{} undefined"
